# How to display Current date in HTML?

Tags: php, html

How to display Current date (DD mon YYYY) in HTML, this has to be implemented in Php code

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0rem 1rem;">
  <h3>Attendance : {current_date} </h3>
  <hr>
  <p id="Page_MsgBox" style="padding: 0rem 1rem;"></p>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    {$attendance_table}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n =  new Date();
y = n.getFullYear();
m = n.getMonth() + 1;
d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
<p id="date"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<h3>Attendance : <?php echo date('d M Y'); ?></h3>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

A bit more strait and simple solution:

```
<h3>Attendance : <?=date('d F Y')?></h3>
```

- F - Full month name
- M - Short (3 symbols) month name
- m - month number
- d - day of month
- Y - full year

Answer (score -1):

```
...    

str_replace("{current_date}",date("d-m-Y"));

...
```

You mean like this ?